# What does to_ms = -1 do on winpcap and linux libpcap?

Tags: macos, libpcap

I am trying to port a libpcap based program to macos, and it seems to be written for windows and linux. In the pcap_open_live function, the read timeout was set to -1, same with PacketOpen, and on macOS, this causes an error when trying to open the interface, BIOCSRTIMEOUT: Invalid Argument. I am unable to find any documentation on what a -1 read timeout actually does. Additonally, is there a version of this which will allow me to do the same thing on a BPF based libpcap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What does to_ms = -1 do on winpcap and linux libpcap?

Nothing predictable.  To quote the tip-of-the-master-branch pcap(3pcap) man page:

```
   packet buffer timeout
      If,  when  capturing,  packets  are  delivered  as  soon as they
      arrive, the application capturing the packets will be  woken  up
      for  each  packet  as  it arrives, and might have to make one or
      more calls to the operating system to fetch each packet.

      If, instead, packets are not delivered as soon as  they  arrive,
      but  are  delivered after a short delay (called a "packet buffer
      timeout"), more than one packet can be  accumulated  before  the
      packets are delivered, so that a single wakeup would be done for
      multiple packets, and each set of calls made  to  the  operating
      system  would  supply  multiple  packets,  rather  than a single
      packet.  This reduces the per‐packet CPU overhead if packets are
      arriving  at  a  high rate, increasing the number of packets per
      second that can be captured.

      The packet buffer timeout is required  so  that  an  application
      won’t  wait for the operating system’s capture buffer to fill up
      before packets are delivered; if packets  are  arriving  slowly,
      that wait could take an arbitrarily long period of time.

      Not  all platforms support a packet buffer timeout; on platforms
      that don’t, the packet buffer timeout is ignored.  A zero  value
      for the timeout, on platforms that support a packet buffer time‐
      out, will cause a read to wait forever to allow  enough  packets
      to arrive, with no timeout.

      NOTE:  the  packet  buffer timeout cannot be used to cause calls
      that read packets to return within a  limited  period  of  time,
      because, on some platforms, the packet buffer timeout isn’t sup‐
      ported, and, on other platforms, the timer doesn’t  start  until
      at  least one packet arrives.  This means that the packet buffer
      timeout should NOT be  used,  for  example,  in  an  interactive
      application  to  allow  the  packet capture loop to ‘‘poll’’ for
      user input periodically, as there’s no  guarantee  that  a  call
      reading packets will return after the timeout expires even if no
      packets have arrived.
```

Nothing is said there about a negative timeout; I'll update it to explicitly say that a negative value should not be used.  (Not on Windows, not on macOS, not on Linux, not on *BSD, not on Solaris, not on AIX, not on HP-UX, not on Tru64 UNIX, not on IRIX, not on *anything*.)

By setting the timeout to -1, they probably *intended* to put the `pcap_t` into "non-blocking mode", where an attempt to read will return immediately if there are no packets waiting to be read, rather than waiting for a packet to arrive.  So, instead, provide a timeout of, for example, 100 (meaning 1/10 second) and use `pcap_setnonblock()` after the `pcap_open_live()` call to put the `pcap_t` into non-blocking mode.  That should work on *all* platforms.